# How to check if a server is up or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In PHP I just did: `$fp = @fsockopen(irc.myserver.net, 6667, $errno, $errstr, 2);`

Does Python 2.X also have a function like PHP's `fsockopen()`? If not how else can I check if a server on port 6667 is up or not?

Comment: @Farhan.K Sory, I didn't mean to ping it, I mean to just check whether I can make a connection to it or not.

Comment: http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.fsockopen/ - first link from google (...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [socket module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) can be used to simply check if a port is open or not.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex(('irc.myserver.net', 6667))
if result == 0:
   print "Port is open"
else:
   print "Port is not open"
```

Comment: Is there also a way to set time out? I tried using `sock.settimeout(5)` above the `result = sock.connect_ex(('irc.myserver.net',6667))` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Drago Yes with an exception, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865685/handling-a-timeout-error-in-python-sockets